# Search Algorithm: Combination of two numbers (Proof)

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, dynamic-programming, analysis-of-algorithms

In several applications or examples in Computer Science (Algorithms & Data Structures), one needs to find two numbers $a_S$, $b_S$ out of two different ordered sequences $A$ and $B$ which summed up give a specific number $S$.

The most efficient way of doing this is as follows:

Inputs:
$S$, $A = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]$,
$B = [b_1, b_2, ..., b_m]$

1. set $i = 0$, $j=m$
2. if $a_i + b_j = S$ we're finished
3. if $a_i + b_j < S$ we increase i by 1
4. if $a_i + b_j > S$ we decrease j by 1
5. go to 2.

Although it makes sense intuitively and especially doing examples, I can't get my head around why its so simple, even though we're only checking a minute subset of the combinations possible.

My questions:

1. What is the formal proof?
2. if instead of a $a_i + b_j = S$ we generalise with $f(a_i,b_i) = S$ (e.g. multiplication, or any other arbitrary function) what are the conditions for this algorithm to be correct?

Comment: Who says you are only searching a minute sample?  If there is no such pair, you are going to have to search through a whole lot of terms to be sure.

Comment: @lulu but only about $m+n$ pairs out of $mn$ possible pairs

Comment: As to your second question, any function which is monotone in both variables will work.

Comment: @Henry  True.  $\quad$

Comment: Essentially because if $a_i +b_j <S$ then $a_{i-k}+b_{j} < S$ and $a_{i}+b_{j-k}<S$ for $k \ge 0$ and similarly if $a_i +b_j >S$ then $a_{i+k}+b_{j} > S$ and $a_{i}+b_{j+k}>S$ for $k \ge 0$ so you do do not need to check those cases

Comment: ok. Not that you said it, the proof is actually really easy. Still, feel free to write it down as an answer for me to accept it and you get the points :). Thanks a lot

Comment: Are A and B sorted? If not, then you need to nested loops. to check each element of A with each element of B. 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/VdsbyM

Comment: NoChance, I appreciate the interest, but I'm not looking for the algorithm that solves it, let alone the brute force algorithm you posted. I'm specifically asking for the proof of correctness for the algorithm I posted above, which has an $O(m+n)$ complexity, and as mentioned only a minute subset of the brute force (yours) one running in $O(mn)$. A and B as mentioned are ordered (sorted).

Comment: Maybe you want to add an exist condition to the algorithm.